# Ethernet cables along with power cords in Dell Cable Management Arm

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, cable, cable-management

Recently I read that placing together Ethernet cables and power cords is not a good thing (many sites and good-practice articles says that). For example:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-things-you-shouldnt-do-when-running-network-cable/
One person even saw ping times go up and down when he moved power cable that run along with cat5e cable.

But Dell is selling Cable Management Arm in which one should place all cables, ethernet, power cables, KVM cables together, along in this Arm. This is obviously in contradiction to the abovementioned "rule".
http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/business/solutions/whitepapers/en/Documents/CMA.pdf

Also the Arm blocks somewhat the exhausted warm air. We have dozens of Dell servers and from behind it is basically a wall of Management Arms.

What is your opinion on this? And could someone point to a technical source that specificaly says that placing ethernet and power cables along is bad? And if it is bad, why Dell makes their Arms like they do?

There is a similiar question, but the answers are: "rather not", "maybe", "you should", "it will ruin the heat flow", "it will not". No one gave a source or a hard case.
[Cable Routing: Can I route power and network cable through a Server Arm?](https://serverfault.com/questions/414086/cable-routing-can-i-route-power-and-network-cable-through-a-server-arm?rq=1)

Best Regards
Kamil

Comment: The arms look pretty much unnecessary to me.  I would think that differential signalling would fix most of the potential for mains induced noise on the Ethernet cable, but I wouldn't say it won't affect it for certain.  I certainly don't like the way they interfere with airflow.